# Assigning text colors to individual dropdownbox list items

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This is a WinForms Application in VB. In my application I am trying to make it easier for the user to pick out items in a list quickly based on the items text color.. So I am trying to assign the color to each item using a select case statement as below... The problem is that I am getting an error saying "Public member 'Attributes' on type 'String' not found." VB flags the lines with the Attribute.Add param with this error.. Here is the code that I currently have...

```
   For Each u In _units
                _counter += 1
                u_lookupNumber_box.Items.Add((Convert.ToString(u.UnitId)) + " - " + (Convert.ToString(u.perMonthCost)))
                Select Case u.occupied
                    Case Is = 0
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).Attributes.add("style", "color: Yellow")
                    Case Is = 1
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).attributes.add("style", "color: Green")
                    Case Is = 2
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).attributes.add("style", "color: Red")
                    Case Is = 3
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).attributes.add("style", "color: Blue")
                    Case Is = 4
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).attributes.add("style", "color: Orange")
                    Case Is = 5
                        u_lookupNumber_box.Items(_counter - 1).attributes.add("style", "color: Purple")
                End Select
            Next
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error?? I did notice that when I did the .attributes part when I hit "." and typed "att" it did not appear in the intelisense box in vb.. Which makes me think I need to assign the name "attributes" somehow to the dropdownbox first.. Thanks for any and all help...

It should be noted that u_lookupNumber_box is the name of the drop down box on my form..

Comment: Looks like `u_lookupNumber_box.Items(x)` returns the text of the item, not the item itself. Also, why are the first two lines in the case sections of every case and not on their own?

Comment: I dunno why I had those 2 redundant lines of code in each.. Above is the revised code. Also u_lookupNumber_box is the name of the dropdownlist and if you notice its u_lookupNumber_box.Items.Add(x) which is adding that item to the list and then in the select case I am attempting to change that items text color inside that dropdownlist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so a long bread crumb trail of searches and a bit of trial and error and I got it to work fully... Because of constant processing of drawItem event arg I am not too happy with it but other than that it works as expected... First I set the DrawMode property of the dropdown to OwnerDrawFixed. Then created a structure in my form class as such:

```
Public Structure ColoredUnitItem
    Dim text As String
    Dim color As Color
    Dim bold As Boolean
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return text
    End Function
End Structure
```

This will actually hold all the attributes for each item..

Next I changed the orginal posted code to the following:

```
For Each u In _units
                _counter += 1
                Dim myItem As New ColoredUnitItem
                With myItem
                    .text = (Convert.ToString(u.UnitId)) + " - " + (Convert.ToString(u.perMonthCost))
                    Select Case u.occupied
                        Case Is = 0
                            .color = Color.Yellow
                        Case Is = 1
                            .color = Color.Green
                        Case Is = 2
                            .color = Color.Red
                        Case Is = 3
                            .color = Color.Blue
                        Case Is = 4
                            .color = Color.Orange
                        Case Is = 5
                            .color = Color.Purple
                    End Select
                End With
                u_lookupNumber_box.Items.Add(myItem)
            Next
```

Next I simply had to draw the dropdownlist on the form as follows:

```
Private Sub uLookUpNumberBox_Draw(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles u_lookupNumber_box.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()
    If Not e.Index = -1 Then
        Dim myItem As ColoredUnitItem = DirectCast(u_lookupNumber_box.Items(e.Index), ColoredUnitItem)
        Dim FontToUse As Font = e.Font
        If myItem.bold Then
            FontToUse = New Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        End If
        e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.text, FontToUse, New SolidBrush(myItem.color), e.Bounds)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    End If
End Sub
```

The flow is easy to follow and does work..

Answer (score 1):

`attributes` is not a method of the [`ListBox.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) property. Look at the [`ListBox.ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx) Class documentation, it gives an example of an `OwnerDrawn ListBox`. I believe this or something similar will be your only option.

Comment: I actually Figured it out... I am working on finishing coding it up now will update my code with the solution when I finish it..